# Расположение объектов по математической функции в цикле (оптимизация)

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика, циклы, оптимизация

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть некоторый список объектов, и их нужно расположить по полуокружности относительно некоего центра:
[image: График функции]
Количество объектов всё время разное и варьируется от 0 до 5. Точки расположения объектов указаны зелёными кружочками; порядок расположения - справа налево.
И, в принципе, мне понятно, какие условия надо проверять, чтобы задать позицию для объекта. Вопрос вот в чём: как оптимизировать ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Count; i++)
{
    while (x != x_center || y != y_center || x != x_center + deltaX || x != x_center - deltaX)
    {
        x -= 0.01f; 
        y = y_center + (float)Math.Sqrt(radius * radius - x * x);
    }
    gameObjects[i].transform.position = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
    x -= 0.01f;
    y = y_center + Mathf.Sqrt(radius * radius - x * x);
    if (x < (x_center - radius)) { break; }
}
```

Программа зависает, так и не выдавая результата, что абсолютно очевидно: через отладку я посмотрел, что цикл while идёт слишком долго. Что можно предпринять? Может, стоит использовать Math.Round() и пренебречь дробными разрядами и точностью? Или есть способ быстро пробегать по математической функции?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Брр... в цикле от `alpha` равно 0 до пи, с промежутком пи/(N-1) (понятно, что для 0 или 1 объекта - уж сами решайте, где находится ничего :)) - получаете `x = R*cos(alpha) + x_center` и `y=R*sin(alpha) + y_center`... Или я чего-то недопонимаю в условии?

Comment: Угол я, к сожалению, не знаю. х) Я могу его вычислить через deltaX и deltaY, но оно мне надо? Я использую уравнение полуокружности: `y = sqrt(R*R - x*x)`.

Comment: Ну и, насколько я понял, Вы предлагаете располагать объекты равноудалённо. А там угол - не 45 градусов.

Comment: Вы располагаете объекты сами. Равномерно. Значит - с одинаковыми углами между ними. Угол для N объектов вы знаете - 180 градусов, или "пи". Все, что еще надо? Скажем, 5 объектов - значит, угол между ними 180/4=45 градусов...

Comment: Я всё прекрасно понимаю, но они должны быть как раз-таки НЕ равноудалёнными. (>w<) Объекты должны находится ТОЛЬКО в этих "зелёных точках" (см. график выше). Это не моя "вредность" по отношению к Вам; просто есть некоторые условия, из-за которых должно быть именно такое расположение объектов.

Comment: Само условие в цикле - скорее всего некорректно. Если вы пытаетесь "остановиться, когда дойдём до точки" - то у вас и будет выполняться это дело бесконечно, т.к. есть погрешность вычисления при числах с плавающей точкой и у Вас значение НИКОГДА не будет равно. К тому же, Вы пытаетесь остановиться, когда дойдёте до середины ровно?.. а если объектов - чётное количество? Так вот, если Вы хотите именно пошагово делать - то проверять нужно не на равенствно/неравенство, а что "точка НЕ ДАЛЬШЕ некоторого дельта" - дельта определить самому (теорию почитайте про абсолютную и относительную погрешность)

Comment: Пока писал - Вы ещё информации докинули. Ну теперь вообще непонятно - а откуда берётся-то это дельта-икс на рисунке? пользователь вводит? И что должно происходить, если объектов 2? просто заполнена первая и вторая точка, справа налево? а по остальным - пусто? или что?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Да, всё так. По остальным пусто. Дельта-икс - просто некоторое известное мне значение, которое вычисляется программно (но я не хочу сейчас расписывать на 10 страниц устройство моего приложения в Unity).

Comment: а еще оптимальней будет задать окружность в полярных координатах и смотреть угол от 180 до 0 через рандом (или какое правило там вы используете) - в таком случае вообще без вложенного цикла можно обойтись, переводя полярные координаты в декартовы

Comment: Тогда вы некорректно сформулировали условие. При плохом ТЗ и результат ХЗ...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я понял, что надо задавать условия в цикле while с погрешностями. Отдельное спасибо Александру, который ответил мне в комментариях.

Если возникнут проблемы - напишу сюда; если нет - тема закрыта.

Comment: Мне с самого начала не понятно, что же вы делаете. У вас есть объекты у которых вычисленны дельта Х и нужно их с учётом этого дельта расположить на окружности? Если так, то мне ваши вычисления вооьще не понятны. Считаете один раз дельта Y и к ней прибавляет Y начальную, а к дельта Х начальную Х - это и есть координаты точки с заданной дельта Х и центром. А у вас какие-то условия, погрешности...

Comment: Вообще странно, что преподаватель об этом не сказал. Наш учитель в школе всех, кто спрашивал "что не так" по этому поводу - всем задавал наводящие вопросы и в итоге сами догадывались. Но уж на дом оставлять такое - издевательство над детьми, я считаю.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Ну, это не в школе. ':D Это собственный проектик. Я на подработке, а мой, э-э-э... наниматель-сотрудник просто смотрит и направляет в нужное русло. В самом Unity не шарит, поэтому все нюансы либо сам выясняю, либо стараюсь достаточно понятно задавать вопросы на форумах Unity, Vuforia и StackOverflow.